# Image won't display in PDF using FOP 1.1 and Java

Tags: java, apache-fop

I've searched Google through and through and can't seem to find the solution to my issue...

I'm using Apache FOP 1.1 and Java to generate a PDF file from Java classes.  This Java project runs from a JAR file.  I am using an image that is external to the JAR itself.  The XSL file that is used to generate the PDF contains this:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="file:///C:/images/image.jpg" width="7.5in" />
```

Based on much searching/reading, I've tried many different variations of the src attribute:

```
src="file:///C:/images/image.jpg"
src="C:/images/image.jpg"
src="url('file:///C:/images/image.jpg')"
src="url('C:/images/image.jpg')"
```

all without success...

Now, here's the confusing part.  I am doing my development from Eclipse IDE and when using the variations of src attribute:

```
src="C:/images/image.jpg"
src="url('C:/images/image.jpg')"
```

The PDF is created properly with the images embedded.

I can not figure out what is keeping the image from being displayed when running from the JAR file...

Thanks in advance! (hopefully)

Devin

Answer (score 0):

The syntax

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('C:/images/image.jpg')" content-height="100%" content-width="100%"/>
```

works perfectly fine for me, both from Eclipse or from a JAR. Have figured out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I had a similar problem and eventually figured out a partial fix.  It was a combo of 2 things:

1. Difference between JVMs in dev and deployed environments (for me raw sun ... err oracle vs. ibm websphere bundled java)
2. **IBM JVM doesn't like indexed PNG files**.  As soon as I converted it to RGB it worked.

Here is the error message I got when I manually ran the fop.bat file with websphere jvm:

```
SEVERE: Image not available. URI: /tmp/image.png. Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: I/O error while extracting image metadata: Error reading PNG metadata (See position 30:182)
```

btw, i was using fop 1.0 + java 1.6 + WAS 7.0 (java 1.6)

Hope this helps someone else!